# Flutter RawKeyboardListener listening twice?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

What I am trying to achieve is when viewing this widget, the `RawKeyboardListener` starts listening straight away when the `TextField` is not selected/in focus. It runs the `HandleKey function` to deal with what I want to do with the `keyCode`.

The issue I am having is when running the app for the first time, the `handleKey function` seems to be running twice. So in the example below it would print `why does this run twice $_keyCode` TWICE when I only enter 1 key. I think it listens to keyUp AND keyDown. The result I want is for it to only run once...

However, the code works fine as well when I select the TextField and do a regular submit with the emulator keyboard.

I am struggling to understand why it only has a problem after interacting with the TextField. I feel like it needs a `Future` or `await` somewhere? but I have no idea.

Please help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class KeyboardListener extends StatefulWidget {

    KeyboardListener();

    @override
    _RawKeyboardListenerState createState() => new _RawKeyboardListenerState();
}

class _RawKeyboardListenerState extends State<KeyboardListener> {

    TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    FocusNode _textNode = new FocusNode();


    @override
        initState() {
        super.initState();
    }
    
    //Handle when submitting
    void _handleSubmitted(String finalinput) {

        setState(() {
            SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide'); //hide keyboard again
            _controller.clear();
        });
    }

    handleKey(RawKeyEventDataAndroid key) {
        String _keyCode;
        _keyCode = key.keyCode.toString(); //keycode of key event (66 is return)

        print("why does this run twice $_keyCode");
    }

    _buildTextComposer() {
        TextField _textField = new TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
        );

        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textNode);

        return new RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: _textNode,
            onKey: (key) => handleKey(key.data),
            child: _textField
        );
    }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Search Item")),
      body: _buildTextComposer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's intended to notify key press and key release.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your callback is getting called for both keydown and keyup events with instances of following classes:

- RawKeyDownEvent
- RawKeyUpEvent

You can pass the whole object to handleKey, and filter based on runtime type of object. for example

```
  handleKey(RawKeyEvent key) {
    print("Event runtimeType is ${key.runtimeType}");
    if(key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent'){
        RawKeyEventDataAndroid data = key.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;
        String _keyCode;
        _keyCode = data.keyCode.toString(); //keycode of key event (66 is return)

        print("why does this run twice $_keyCode");
    }
  }

  _buildTextComposer() {
      TextField _textField = new TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
      );

      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textNode);

      return new RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: _textNode,
          onKey: handleKey,
          child: _textField
      );
  }
```

If this still does not help, check actual runtimeTypes logged from handleKey method, and filter by those.

Comment: afaik this listener only works for physical keyboards, it doesn't work for 'soft' keyboard, right?

Comment: I would rather use the instance-of kind operator: key is RawKeyDownEvent

Comment: Beware that this would not work in a production release where runtimeType will get optimized out, i.e. is not available.

Answer (score 15):

The `onKey` callback is triggered for both **key down** and **key up** events. That's why it appears to be called twice for a single key press.

When handling the events, I prefer using `is` rather than accessing the runtime type:

```dart
onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
  if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
    // handle key down
  } else if (event is RawKeyUpEvent) {
    // handle key up
  }
},
```

Comment: Perfect! Best answer, although should explain what the others have already i.e. that two events are triggering

Answer (score 5):

Using `isKeyPressed` worked for me.

**My Working code**

```
RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: _focusNodeKeyboard,
                  onKey: (event) {
                    if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace)) {
                      print('Backspace Pressed'); // Printed Once
                    }
                  },
                )
```

**Older Version**

```
RawKeyboardListener(
                  focusNode: _focusNodeKeyboard,
                  onKey: (event) {
                    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
                     print('Backspace Pressed'); // Printed Twice
                    }
                  },
                )
```

Comment: that should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Eyo, played around with the values variables and noticed that if you use the iskeypressed
on the second time round it's false. Id hazard a guess that normally its either detecting the press  and the release.

so

```
    RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: FocusNode(),
                autofocus: true,
                //includeSemantics: true,
                onKey: (value){

                  print("1) ${value.data}");
                  print("2) ${value.character.toString()}");
                  print("3) ${value.toString()}");
                  print("4) ${value.physicalKey.debugName}");
                  print("5) ${value.logicalKey.keyId}");
                  print("6) ${value.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)}");


                  setState(() {
                   
                    ///add string to list and clear text or not ?
                    value.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter ? print("YES A") : 0;
                    value.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) ? print("YES B") : 0;
                    }
                  );
                },
```

Results in a

```
    flutter: 1) Instance of 'RawKeyEventDataWindows'
flutter: 2) 

flutter: 3) RawKeyDownEvent#13d45(logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#70028(keyId: "0x100070028", keyLabel: "Enter", debugName: "Enter"), physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#70028(usbHidUsage: "0x00070028", debugName: "Enter"))
flutter: 4) Enter
flutter: 5) 4295426088
flutter: 6) true
flutter: YES A
flutter: YES B
flutter:  NEXT SET
flutter: ***********************************
flutter: 1) Instance of 'RawKeyEventDataWindows'
flutter: 2) null
flutter: 3) RawKeyUpEvent#9dc07(logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#70028(keyId: "0x100070028", keyLabel: "Enter", debugName: "Enter"), physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#70028(usbHidUsage: "0x00070028", debugName: "Enter"))
flutter: 4) Enter
flutter: 5) 4295426088
flutter: 6) false
flutter: YES A
flutter:  NEXT SET
flutter: ***********************************
```

Comment: ah just realised 
RawKeyUpEvent#9dc07
RawKeyDownEvent#13d45

Answer (score 3):

You are right. `RawKeyboardListener` listens on raw keyboard events. Which means it returns down and up (or how the naming convention is on touchscreens). Knowing that you could simply create a if-statement and just get through the event once:

```
bool _tempKeyPressedOnce = false;
if (!_tempKeyPressedOnce) {
    // do stuff
    _tempKeyPressedOnce = true;
}
```

Comment: But how do I access the `RawKeyDownEvent` or whatever I need to get to see if it is only a keydown or up so I can then use a bool on it

Comment: Something like this: `RawKeyDownEvent keyDownEvent = key; keyDownEvent.data;`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get it to work:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
  focusNode: FocusNode(),
  onKey: (event) {
    // Only taking key down event into consideration
    if (event.runtimeType == RawKeyDownEvent) {
      bool shiftPressed = event.isShiftPressed; // true: if shift key is pressed
    }
  },
  child: TextField(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to write values from the keyboard

```
          handleKey(RawKeyEvent event) {
            if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
              if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                log('ENTER');
                _text = '';
              } else {
                log('Event data keyLabel ${event.data.keyLabel}');
                _text += event.data.keyLabel;
              }
              log('text: $_text');
            }
          }
```

It does not duplicate writing values from the keyboard