# Get keypress value without textfield focus in flutter web using RawKeyboardListener

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I'm playing around writing a "snake" video game for flutter web.  I'd like to use the arrow keys to move around, but I've been unable to capture keypresses using RawKeyboardListener.  I believe it is due to the fact that I don't have the correct node in focus. At this point, I'm just trying to print out the keystrokes that I'm receiving.

Here's my test code:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: FocusNode(),      //<-- I'm not sure what to put here... and it's required.
        onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
          print(event.data.logicalKey.keyId);
        },
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 300,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 30),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: getPixels(index));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution... but I still don't entirely understand it.  I finally started putting as much as I could from Textfield examples of RawKeyboardListener and I ran into this answer: [Flutter RawKeyboardListener listening twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985342/flutter-rawkeyboardlistener-listening-twice) as well as the example in this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50854

Using the commonalities as a template, this is the code the ended up working, and I hope it helps someone else. (and I'd love to understand what, exactly, is happening):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';  //<-- needed for the keypress comparisons

FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();  // <-- still no idea what this is.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode); // <-- yup.  magic. no idea.
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: RawKeyboardListener(
          autofocus: true,
          focusNode: focusNode,   // <-- more magic
          onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
            if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown) {
               direction = "down";
               }
            if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
               direction = "left";
               }
            if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
               direction = "right";
               }
            if (event.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
               direction = "up";
               }
          },
          child: GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 300,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 30),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: getPixels(index));
              },
            ),
          ),
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `autofocus: true,`

According to docs,

> True if this widget will be selected as the initial focus when no
> other node in its scope is currently focused. ... Defaults to false.

Comment: Hey Logan, thanks for your input!  I didn't notice the "autoFocus" parameter in the docs... thanks for bringing it to my attention!  I'm bummed that it didn't fix the problem, I kept getting a 'primaryContext != null' error in the services library.  I did come up with a solution, but I'm still not positive why it works... but it does have to do with that focusNode parameter.  In any case, thanks for the help!