# Snap picture in flutter with the volume up button iOS and Android

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement my own camera in flutter. My users have a clicker device via bluetooth that hits the volume up button. So in the Camera app on the phone it will snap a picture. In my app it just turns the volume up.

How can I intercept this volume up event instead of turning the volume up?

I have tried wrapping my camera in the RawKeyboardListener like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552871/get-keypress-value-without-textfield-focus-in-flutter-web-using-rawkeyboardliste) but it doesn't seem to be meant for this and I am having difficulties with the focus and it triggering any events at all. Packages I find on pub_dev are either deprecated or work for android only.

Is it really that hard to detect a button press on a users device in flutter? Even if I can, will the volume still be changed? I want to remove the volume changing effect and just trigger my own event (snap a picture).