# How to prevent keyborad from popping up in the whole app flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

I am building an app in flutter for android pos device. but i want to hide the keyboard
when clicking on the textfield. how can i achieve that ?

I've tried the following code

FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();

when i calling this code nothing can be entered and the third or fourth tap keyboard popes again

Comment: you can try to disable the text field if you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TextField(
  showCursor: true,
  readOnly: true),
```

found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60106951/12838877

Comment: But this doesnt allow physical keyboard to input

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
InkWell(
  onTap: (){
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  },
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: true,
    child: TextField(),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It doesnt work. after calling unFocus() method nothing is entering

Comment: you've said that i want to hide the keyboard when clicking on the textfield so it work on that , can you explain actually what type of functionality you want to achieve like after some keywords you want to hide keyboard

Comment: Not like that. im building this application for pos device runs in android. So there will be physical keyboard, so i dont want inbuilt keyboard to popup rest should work as default

Comment: You'll get some idea from here, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985342/flutter-rawkeyboardlistener-listening-twice

Detailed class explanation,
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html